# How to implement guards and interceptor in android

Tags: android, http

in angularjs there are the concepts of guards (check if you are fulfilling certain requirements to access a specific page) and of interceptors (they add data to a http request).

How can I implement those two concepts on android? 
Can you point me to tutorials about it?

Thanks